# OR-Tools: Adding a constraint to min cost flow class?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

I'm trying to solve the supply chain network flow problem using or-tools. I have got demand and supply nodes with capacities and demand for arcs. I have managed to get the optimal result using SolveMaxFlowWithMinCost().

But I'm trying to find a solution where each demand node can only be serviced by 1 supply node. Is there anyway I could add this constraint to the model?

Answer (score 0):

Gut reaction is that you cannot add any constraint to the min cost flow, nor expect any property like fairness. As soon as you do that, you change complexity from polynomial (min cost flow) to NP-complete.

You can try an integer solver (MPSOlver, CP-SAT) but performance will be much worse.

You can also try to postprocess the output of the min cost flow to repair the assignment.

Last idea, you can use the min cost flow assignment to restrict the model for the NP solvers (only keeping arcs that appear in the min cost flow for instance).

Comment: Thanks Laurent, I guessed so. I was thinking if there is some workaround that could enable this condition. But I think post processing is the way forward for now.